# Change beamer compiled defaults to Finnish

Tags: beamer, languages

I have a beamer title page

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\title{Epic title}
\author{vahvero}
\institute{Epic institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

This produces a page

[image: Wrong Who? From? When?]

How can I change the Who?, From?, When? to "Kuka?", "Mistä?", "Milloin?"?
Is there some beamer themes that support Finnish language defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beamer uses the translator package to translate, but there is no finnish dictionary, you could use the english dictionary as a template and fill in all the needed words (I changed only the three from the title page as an example). Once you have a full translation you can send it to the maintainer then he can include it: https://github.com/josephwright/translator/issues.

Set also the language as class option to that the package can pick it up.

```
\begin{filecontents}{translator-basic-dictionary-Finnish.dict}
\ProvidesDictionary{translator-basic-dictionary}{Finnish}
%  translate that:
\providetranslation{Abstract}{Abstract}
\providetranslation{Addresses}{Addresses}
\providetranslation{addresses}{addresses}
\providetranslation{Address}{Address}
\providetranslation{address}{address}
\providetranslation{and}{and}
\providetranslation{Appendix}{Appendix}
\providetranslation{Authors}{Authors}
\providetranslation{authors}{authors}
\providetranslation{Author}{Author}
\providetranslation{author}{author}
\providetranslation{Bibliography}{Bibliography}
\providetranslation{cc}{cc}
\providetranslation{Chapters}{Chapters}
\providetranslation{chapters}{chapters}
\providetranslation{Chapter}{Chapter}
\providetranslation{chapter}{chapter}
\providetranslation{Conclusion}{Conclusion}
\providetranslation{conclusion}{conclusion}
\providetranslation{Contents}{Contents}
\providetranslation{Continuation}{Continuation}
\providetranslation{continuation}{continuation}
\providetranslation{cont}{cont}
\providetranslation{encl (plural)}{encl}
\providetranslation{encl (singular)}{encl}
\providetranslation{encl}{encl}
\providetranslation{Figures}{Figures}
\providetranslation{figures}{figures}
\providetranslation{Figure}{Figure}
\providetranslation{figure}{figure}
\providetranslation{From}{From}
\providetranslation{from}{from}
\providetranslation{Glossary}{Glossary}
\providetranslation{Index}{Index}
\providetranslation{Introduction}{Introduction}
\providetranslation{introduction}{introduction}
\providetranslation{List of Figures and Tables}{List of Figures and Tables}
\providetranslation{List of Figures}{List of Figures}
\providetranslation{List of Tables}{List of Tables}
\providetranslation{or}{or}
\providetranslation{Outline}{Outline}
\providetranslation{Overview}{Overview}
\providetranslation{Pages}{Pages}
\providetranslation{pages}{pages}
\providetranslation{Page}{Page}
\providetranslation{page}{page}
\providetranslation{Paragraphs}{Paragraphs}
\providetranslation{paragraphs}{paragraphs}
\providetranslation{Paragraph}{Paragraph}
\providetranslation{paragraph}{paragraph}
\providetranslation{Parts}{Parts}
\providetranslation{parts}{parts}
\providetranslation{Part}{Part}
\providetranslation{part}{part}
\providetranslation{Preface}{Preface}
\providetranslation{Proofs}{Proofs}
\providetranslation{proofs}{proofs}
\providetranslation{Proof}{Proof}
\providetranslation{proof}{proof}
\providetranslation{References}{References}
\providetranslation{Related work}{Related work}
\providetranslation{Related Work}{Related Work}
\providetranslation{Sections}{Sections}
\providetranslation{sections}{sections}
\providetranslation{Section}{Section}
\providetranslation{section}{section}
\providetranslation{See also}{See also}
\providetranslation{see also}{see also}
\providetranslation{See}{See}
\providetranslation{see}{see}
\providetranslation{Sketch of Proofs}{Sketch of Proofs}
\providetranslation{Sketch of proofs}{Sketch of proofs}
\providetranslation{Sketch of Proof}{Sketch of Proof}
\providetranslation{Sketch of proof}{Sketch of proof}
\providetranslation{Subsections}{Subsections}
\providetranslation{subsections}{subsections}
\providetranslation{Subsection}{Subsection}
\providetranslation{subsection}{subsection}
\providetranslation{Summary}{Summary}
\providetranslation{Tables}{Tables}
\providetranslation{tables}{tables}
\providetranslation{Table}{Table}
\providetranslation{table}{table}
\providetranslation{To}{To}
\providetranslation{to}{to}
% example:
\providetranslation{Who?}{Kuka?}
\providetranslation{From?}{Mistä?}
\providetranslation{When?}{Milloin?}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[finnish]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\title{Epic title}
\author{vahvero}
\institute{Epic institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not get similar output to yours from this code. `pdflatex tmp.tex` still contains the English defaults. What could cause this?

Comment: To make things more confusing, this works on overleaf, but no locally. I will assert that this is the correct solution. My compiler does something odd.

Comment: is your local system older? And which texlive do you use on overleaf?

Comment: I had `pdflatex` 1.40.20, Overleaf uses `1.40.24` and when I installed from `1.40.25` which still does not work. This could be already an another question.

Comment: Compile my example and show the log-file.

Comment: I managed to get this to work on 1.40.25. I had wrong path to 1.40.20 in my `$PATH`. Would you still like to see the log file on 1.40.20?